# Seamless prints?

Tags: prusa-i3, 3d-design, slic3r, slicing

Is there a way to make all your prints seamless?? I know there was this program that printed a vase constantly changing the z axis making it seamless. Why cant this be done with regular prints?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you ever seen 3d printouts on your own and you did keep it in hand then you probably felt layers. Most printouts contains 3 main "components"

1. bottom and top component (floor and ceiling)
2. outline (perimeters)
3. infill (inside supporting structure)

It is almost imposible (and for sure sensless) to create all these components with one continues line as it would be very complex and sophisticated line.

Second reason. It would be very often that printer would cross outlines (perimeters) so it would destroy good looking external surface.

And third reason. Objects can have "islands". Imagine printed elephant which is standing on 4 legs. How to draw leg leyers with one line if these legs are separated (at the floor level).

That's why "round vase" is the only option to print seamless. :)

Answer (score 2):

With Cura (a 3d printing software) you can go to the Expert tab and click Open Settings and you will see under an area called Black Magic, an option to Spiralize the outer contour.

Answer (score 1):

Look into post processing your model with an [Acetone vapor Bath.](http://makezine.com/2014/09/24/smoothing-out-your-3d-prints-with-acetone-vapor/).  ABS plastic disolves in acetone.   if you put your print in a chamber full of acetone vapor, the outer skin will sort of melt, and give you the effect you are looking for. The goal is to leave it in long enough that the outer skin melts a bit.  Too short a time, and you don't get enough melting.  Too long a time and more than the skin melts, and the print may deform.

Comment: Thanks, I might just get use to the look, I know there was this guy in youtube who got this stuff that gave it a glazed/glossy look and gave it a smooth surface.

Comment: @ChrisManning It's a bit strange you've changed "accepted answer" because you did ask "Why cant this be done with regular prints?" Acetone vapor bath is definitely not regular print.

Comment: I was trying to like the comment/answer. I just now realized it was changing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use Simplify3d as my slicer, and this has a 'vase' mode.  You end up with a single wall thickness and it only works on simple shapes without supports.

You get no infill or top surface, so it only works for certain shapes; vases for example!!